# No accelerated colorspace conversion found

Tags: ros, opencv, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i try to run some custom node to process some .avi video i have this error : i guess this error is related to opencv , i have tried all the sloutions , even recompiled vision_opencv with FFMPEG flag on , and urgraded ffmped with --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-swscale , but still no luck .

```
[swscaler @ 0x842fa20]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
[swscaler @ 0x848aa80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
Last message repeated 10 times
[swscaler @ 0x8497c80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
[swscaler @ 0x848aa80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
Last message repeated 10 times
[swscaler @ 0x8497c60]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
[swscaler @ 0x848aa80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
Last message repeated 10 times
[swscaler @ 0x8495730]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
[swscaler @ 0x848aa80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
Last message repeated 10 times
[swscaler @ 0x8492ae0]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
[swscaler @ 0x848aa80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
Last message repeated 10 times
[swscaler @ 0x8492d00]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
[swscaler @ 0x848aa80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
Last message repeated 10 times
[swscaler @ 0x8491c70]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
[swscaler @ 0x848aa80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found
```

i can't proceed with my project , until i sort this out and i already have wasted more than 10hrs on this problem , so if  you guys think of any solution i would be glad to try it out .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10262/no-accelerated-colorspace-conversion-found/) by [rajat](https://answers.ros.org/users/591/rajat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 175 on 2011-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rajat](https://answers.ros.org/users/591/rajat/) on 2011-06-19**:
i converted the avi file to the standard avi file format used by openCV using "mencoder in.avi -ovc raw -vf format=i420 -o out.avi ",so i guess the file is not the problem. Actually don't worry about it, as the problem was something else ,this was just a warning.sorry for the inconvenience caused  .

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-06-16**:
What's the content/properties of the avi movie? How does your code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an ffmpeg bug/feature: not all conversions are accelerated. When compiling my own ffmepg 0.6.2 or 0.7 rc1, those warnings disappeared (the Ubuntu version seems to have them). Not sure of the flags to use though.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3